# Pythonanywhere "permission denied" when reading an executable file

Tags: python, linux, permissions, selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere

I'd like to use Selenium via python anywhere. I've tested my script locally and all is well. One key note is that chromedriver is a required executable file. I uploaded it to the directory, `/home/user/docs/chromedriver`. When I pass this path to the function as it expects, a permissions error is returned `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium. org/chromedriver/home`.

When I check the permissions of the file I get:

```
$ ls -l chromedriver 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user registered_users 11924296 Sep 24 01:21 chromedriver
```

I'm not 100% sure what this means, however, I expected an `x` to be present as its an executable file. Should I change permissions (what to and how)?
Any other recommendations?

Comment: `chmod 755 chromedriver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a chromedriver installed on PythonAnywhere that works with the Chrome that is available on PythonAnywhere. You do not need to upload one of your own and, if you do not get the version correct, it will not work.